# How to change the orientation of a list of small pictures from one column for a large desktop to one row on phones?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I use Bootstrap and going to make responsive views both for large desktop and phones.

This is my row section:

```
<div class="row-fluid section2">
    <div class="span3 offset1 asset">
      <img class="img-polaroid"  alt="Placeholder" src="http://placehold.it/240x300">
    </div>
    <div class="span7 asset copy">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
        porta, dui sagittis hendrerit rutrum, nunc leo tempus nisl, eu
        mollis justo velit at nunc. Fusce nec egestas sem. Donec
        fringilla ante lectus, a pellentesque lacus dignissim ac. Sed
        volutpat lorem ut congue malesuada. In facilisis scelerisque
        turpis sed lacinia. Donec in orci lectus. Donec auctor semper
        quam, eget rhoncus purus fringilla id. Phasellus id nibh eu
        risus ultrices adipiscing.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta, dui sagittis hendrerit
        rutrum, nunc leo tempus nisl, eu mollis justo velit at
      </p>
    </div>
<div class="span1 asset">
  <div class="row-fluid">
         <img class="img-polaroid"  alt="Placeholder" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
         <img class="img-polaroid"  alt="Placeholder" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
         <img class="img-polaroid"  alt="Placeholder" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
         <img class="img-polaroid"  alt="Placeholder" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It looks like this in Chrome on a large desktop:
[image]

But phone's landscape is not good and looks like this:
[image]

You can notice that small 50X50 pictures are still in one column and don't look good.

How can I rotate my four 50X50 pictures from one column for large desktop to one row on phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way : You can play with **Css media query**.

In reading the [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive)  you can find the good media queries you need for each device.

**Css:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .asset .row-fluid{
        float:left;
        width:auto;   
    }
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/745/)**